# White frame around listbox Item selection on Windows8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, listbox

I am getting complaints from `Windows8` users about a strange frame around the `SelectedItem` on `ListBoxes`

In `Windows7` this issue does not exists and so far I have found no way to get rid of this white frame.

As far as I can tell `Windows8` listboxes now use `ControlBrushKey` instead of `HighlightBrushKey` but setting that to `Transparent` has no affect.

I have no Windows8 development environment at the moment so all fixes I have tried are pure guess work.

ListBox Resources:

```
 <ListBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />

     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
     </Style>
 </ListBox.Resources>
```

The entire Xaml can be found here: https://github.com/saddam213/MPDisplay/blob/master/GUIFramework/GUI/Controls/GUIList.xaml

Image of the frame: (white box around selection)

[image]

If anyone has a clue how to get rid of this it would be great.

Comment: Try this is this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255416/setting-systemcolors-overrides-in-an-implicit-style

Comment: Attach a compiled .EXE what can be run and tested for this bug, I will tell you how to disable that.

Comment: @ss_ddam213 is the linked xaml the right one? cos the `Orientation` on `StackPanel` set to `Horizontal`. However, you screen shows otherwise.

Comment: @sthotakura, It is configurable, it has 3 views Horizontal, Vertical and Coverflow, It is set in the VirtualizingStackpanels Triggers, all views get the same rectangle. I think I will just install a Win8 VM and try find the issue.

Comment: Upload complete project that will allow us to try out your issue.

Comment: @devhedgehog, Its not that simple, but you can download from here http://mpdisplay2.de/index.php/en/download-section1/latest-plugin-version, but this is a plugin for another application so you would need to install that aswell http://www.team-mediaportal.com/mediaportal-download, or create a new window with the skin editor with a list you can test with, But I think I will just have to install Windows8 , I was just hoping someone knew what it was before I did that, Or you can just compile the source code from the link in the question

Comment: It is the default style of ListBoxItem causing that problem/freature. You have placed a style for ListBoxItem in your resources still the ListBoxItem has its default style which is also in use. I was asking for code to see all the available styles. Could you try setting BorderThickness in your ListBoxItem style and tell su what happens. (Nicht in default style von ListBoxItem) :)

Comment: @devhedgehog, this is the only defined style for listbox, there is no other ListBoxes used, I have tried border thickness, color, backgrounds everything so it seems to be something else, because this only happened on Windows8 I thought it could be a well known issue here. I will just have install Windows8 and fix, thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: It might be the only style you defined in your code for ListBox or ListBox item but there is the default style which every control in wpf has. In every case where you have a custom style defined somewhere in resources the control will consider your style but also the default style. Try to write your own ControlTemplate and place it inside the custom style you defined and you will notice the difference.

Comment: @devhedgehog, I am not going to rebuild a control just because of a brush that needs to be overridden, I just will not support Windows8 if I need to override a entire ListBox template to remove a selection color, it will be simple once I install Win8 to find the brush using snoop

Comment: @devhedgehog, OK so it seems the Windows 8 theme doesn't use system colors for the foreground/background colors, so overriding them doesn't work any more. Looks like win8 users are stuck with this "feature" for a while, Thanks again for the help

Comment: Just upload your project somewhere online please and I ll gladly take a look at the code. Then I will able to provide you with futher details. I dont know what you mean with overriding them doesn't work any more.

Comment: well in windows7 I just have to override `HighlightBrushKey` to remove the listboxitem highlight, but this does not work for windows8 because Areo2 does not use `SystemColors`, project is on github https://github.com/saddam213/MPDisplay/blob/master/GUIFramework/GUI/Controls/GUIList.xaml

Comment: don't try to delete that border. Just give the same color as background to the border.

Comment: Your solution is not working at all. Your dll references are broken in every project and visual studio needs admin rights to even load your solution. Futhermore even when I solve all your reference issues and build files from scratch I still never get the change to display anything because your code always runs into null reference execeptions. You seem to be asking for many files locally but they are not created on build. Seems you forgot to change the build options on your resources and dlls. It might run for you because you already have all you need in bin folder but I dont. Please repair it

Answer (score 2):

In a comment in your original post, you said:

> I am not going to rebuild a control just because of a brush that needs to be overridden, I just will not support Windows8 if I need to override a entire ListBox template to remove a selection color, it will be simple once I install Win8 to find the brush using snoop

However, it is not painfully difficult to "rebuild" the `ListBoxItem`. It may, in fact, be simpler than forcing brushes, as you do not need to worry about overriding every UX change between Windows versions. One particular app I am building right now has the requirement that it run on every OS from XP to 8.1; I achieved a uniform look across all OSes by customizing everything down to the window borders.

Your best bet would be to style *every aspect* of the `ListBoxItem` by creating a template, something like the following:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Obviously, you would need to modify the styles to get the exact behavior you want.

Comment: I know it's simple to override the template, I just find it frustrating that I have to do this to satisfy a single OS, when it all previous versions 1 line of xaml would have done the trick.

Comment: @sa_ddam213: Right now it may be a single OS, but in future versions of Windows you may run across more problems. It's better to just do it right the first time.

Comment: This should work. Except I would make sure that borderBrush is set to Transparent and I would add  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix: I was just telling the OP how to use a template. To tell the truth, I have never found a use for `<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />`; my styles seem to work fine without that line.

Answer (score 1):

i think this may be helpful for you. use Trigger property for isSelected.

```
 <ListBox Name="lst">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Wheat"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                  </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the last answer really helps.
This is how I get rid of the white frames around ListBoxItem:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="Black"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```