# Change font colour inside combo box, data coming from SQL

Tags: sql, wpf, combobox

Hard to put into words for title. I have a normal WPF combo box and the data (list of names) is getting pulled from SQL and I want to change the text colour and

```
Foreground ="Black"
```

only seems to be working when I actually select the user. Any suggestions how else I can change this?

EDIT: I haven't tried any other things as of yet as I know that way to actually change the text colour.

EDIT2:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDepartment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="92,580,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="13"/>
```

This is my XAML code for the combo box. I have figured out that my theme is making it blue but when I change the font colour on my theme everything then turns that colour in my application. Is there a piece of code that I can write in my XAML which will set the colour of everything in the combo box grey, without changing the colours in my application.

Comment: I suggest that you describe your problem better *by editing your question*... *exactly* what text do you want to colour? What have you tried other than `Foreground = "Black"`?

Comment: @Sheridan I have edited question a bit. I don't know what else I can add. I want the text inside the combo box to change which is the data from SQL.

Comment: @BenClarke could you pleas provide some more code ?! your XAML would be nice

Comment: @WiiMaxx Added code and abit more explaination.

Comment: oh it looks like i misunderstand your Question o.O?

Comment: so when should the foreground change his color?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that initially the ComboBox shows no selected value and once you click on it it shows the list of names with the proper color (being whatever color you assigned through the Foreground property).

If so, may it be the case that you haven't selected an item? Once you have set the items, you must select an item (e.g. SelectedIndex, SelectedValue) if you don't want the ComboBox selection to appear empty.

Excuse me if this is not the case, but the question was pretty vague..

Comment: The data for the combo box loads up on page load. When I click the down arrow for the combo box, the items in the combo box are the items I want the colour to change for. I have edited my question abit more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example using MVVM

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SelfBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

codebehind

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace SelfBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            MyItems = new List<MyItem>();
            MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Black" });
            MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Red" });
            MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Orange" });
            MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "Green" });
        }

    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

to test it on your on  create a new WPFproject an copy & past the code

Comment: @WillMaxx So we have to write all that code just to change the colour in a combo box? o.O

Comment: @BenClarke if you want to do it "right" (using the MVVM pattern) you need some more code ^^ (INotifyPropertyChanged)  so you will get the "full power" of WPF ... but you could certainly use Triggers but then you need one Trigger foreach color which would be more mess. There are sure other ways to do this more simpler but i don't know them :) and they wouldn't be WPF friendly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override the theme colors in the combobox resources. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255416/setting-systemcolors-overrides-in-an-implicit-style) is an exaple for doing so.

I just don't know what exactly is the key that you need to override. I guess you can google that.

good luck.